# Unable to edit Redis.conf file in ubuntu 16.04 LTE?

Tags: django, redis, ubuntu-16.04, django-redis

I installed Redis in Ubuntu 16.04 LTE and during configuration i have to edit redis.conf file, but unfortunately i could not be able to save the file, because file is having read-only access
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 46695 Jan 18 19:57 redis.conf
I used chmod 777 redis.conf to get the access writes but it is not happening

chmod: changing permissions of 'redis.conf': Operation not permitted

Thanks in advance for your valuable solution

Comment: sudo vi redis.conf

Comment: That's Perfect. Thanks a lot:-)

Answer (score 0):

`Operation not permitted` is an error thrown when the user through which you logged in doesn't have permission, following should work if you have `sudo` privileges.

```
sudo vi redis.conf
OR
sudo nano redis.conf
OR
sudo gedit redis.conf
```

Choosing editor is based on your personal preferences.